# How to wait in line with Udacity reviewer API in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use the [Udacity reviewer API](https://review.udacity.com/api-doc/) to wait in line to be assigned projects.  However, I'm not able to figure out how to use the `/submission_requests` POST call.  Right now I'm doing this in Python:

```
import requests

TOKEN = os.getenv('udacity_api_key')
BASE_URL = 'https://review-api.udacity.com/api/v1/'
headers = {'Authorization': TOKEN}
req_url = BASE_URL + 'submission_requests'
proj_req_data = {
  "projects": [
    {
      "project_id": 232,
      "language": "en-us"
    }
  ]
}
res = requests.post(req_url, headers=headers, data=proj_req_data)
```

and the response (`print res.content`) is:

```
{"error":"request must have at least one valid project/language pair"}
```

I've also tried 'en' as the language.  I got the `project_id` from the `/me/certifications` GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong argument for the requests.post() function.  If the data is passed as a dict, it needs to be in the `json` arg.  If it is in the `data` arg, it needs to be stringified with `json.dumps()`.

There's a nice Python API code example here: https://github.com/udacity/grading-assigner